# Can speed be defined instead of duration for jQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-easing, custom-scrolling

I've this position that is dependent on dynamic value. It makes sense that shorter distance should be animated faster but with appearance of same amount of acceleration (speed). However, in jquery docs I only see a way to define duration which is ok for lots of things but not for others. How can I define speed so if value is small duration is small too and if value is long then duration is long to. thanks.

Comment: You can compute the distance that the element will be moved, for example, and use that to determine the length of the animation. Unfortunately there is no native way to determining the "speed" or "rate" of an animation.

Comment: @Terry I think you mean "there is *no* native way".

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Indeed. Brain fart recorded at 3.34am ;) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since the jQuery animation only accepts a time, you can calculate the time to give you a specific speed:

```
time = pixels / desired pixels per second
```

So, if the animation covers 200px and the desired speed is 100px / sec, then you simply calculate:

```
time = 200px / 100 px per sec = 2 sec = 2000ms
```

If the animation covers 40px, then you'd have:

```
time = 40px / 100 px per sec = 0.4 sec = 400ms
```

You could also make your own version of jQuery animate that does this work for you using this form of `animate(properties, options)`:

```
jQuery.fn.speedAnimate = function(properties, options, val, rate) {
    options.duration = (val / rate) * 1000;
    return this.animate(properties, options);
}
```

Where `val` is in any units you care to use (pixels might be most common) and `rate` in units/second.

Comment: Of course, for any shaping other than 'linear', the speed will be an average.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Yes.  If the OP's wants a truly constant speed, they should pick the 'linear' easing function.